# Wordpress MultiSite domain mapping

Tags: wordpress

Got a question about Wordpress Multisite. Have it configured on a subdomain (sub.domain.nl) and its working perfectly for subdirectory's. But I can not got it to work with real domains. For example, I want domain www.mydomain.nl mapped to sub.domain.nl/mydomain/. What I have; Installed the domain mapping plugin and configured the domain. The other domain is running on a different server then my multi site installation. Added an A record pointing to the server the multisite installation is running on. Also added a CNAME record pointing to the subdomain the multisite installation is running on. Yet, when I go to the domain name its giving a splash screen of the provider.

Anybody with any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Regards.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but thought that Domain Mapping was only possible with Multisite set up with sub-domains, not directories.

Comment: Yes, I thought that as well, but after some mighty Google'in I found out it should be possible with subdirectory's.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a wildcard as a CNAME? *.domain.com allows wordpress to handle mapping duties rather than your domain provider.

Comment: Yes, the CNAME record is *.spoetnikken.nl as host, value has the subdomain where the multisite installation is running.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could map domains to both a subdomain and a subdirectory, apologies.